# How to query an access database on SharePoint Online

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint-online, vba

I would like to ask you, if there is any way where I can query an Access Database, which is stored on SharePoint, using Excel Vba code and without using the "Get Data" functionality in the Excel.

In other words, how I can connect my excel spreadsheet to the access database on SharePoint Online using ADODB or DAO etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm interested to see if anyone answers this, I tried something similar a while ago on a teamspace (not sharepoint) but it meant downloading the access database each time. I wonder if SharePoint has some in-built functionality. I'm thinking the best way would be to get users to Sync the Access file to their computer and just deal with it as if it was saved to their PC?